# JSF dataTable iterator var conflict

Tags: jsf, facelets

The following works using `_trip` as the iterator variable

```
<h:dataTable var="_trip" value="#{trips}">
   <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header">Trip #</f:facet>
        #{_trip.trip_id}
   </p:column>
```

However, using `trip` as the iterator var doesn't print the `trip_id`

```
<h:dataTable var="trip" value="#{trips}">
   <p:column>
     <f:facet name="header">Trip #</f:facet>
        #{trip.trip_id}
   </p:column>
```

I'm just trying to understand why anything but `trip` works i.e. `aTrip, mytrip, blah` all work in printing out the `trip_id`

Comment: you are missing a '>' in the second snippet for <p:column>

Comment: That was a typo. In my actual code, trip doesn't work but if I add an underscore or another character it works

Comment: Looks like you have another `trip` variable as page, request, session or application attribute in this page.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, right, I'm using Eclipse, which allows me to hover or click on things like #{trips} to see what it is using, but can not do that with the iterator, which I feel should only be in the context of the dataTable anyway. Doing a simple keyword search of my whole project, I'm not seeing anything ovious.

Comment: You may try commenting your `<h:dataTable>` and printing `#{trip}` directly in your Facelet just to check if there's another variable with that name.

Comment: great idea, post an answer for credit.  actually right above the dataTable I simply put #{trip}, then hovered over it and Eclipse lead me right to an old Controller with  /@Produces /@Named
 public Trip getTrip() {
  return trip;
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, the problem was that you already had another variable called `trip` stored as page, request, session or application context. This can be recognized by just outputting this `trip` variable in your facelet content, it may also help commenting the `<h:dataTable>` to avoid any other kind of conflict in the page by using [`<ui:remove>`](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/ui/remove.html):

```html
#{trip}
<ui:remove>
<h:dataTable var="trip" value="#{trips}">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Trip #</f:facet>
        #{trip.trip_id}
    </p:column>
    <!-- the rest of your other JSF/Facelets code... -->
</h:dataTable>
</ui:remove>
```

Comment: yep, I had Produces and Named annotations on a getter Trip getTrip() in an unused (backup copy) of a Controller.